# Is there any HTML URL encoding function freely available on web?? (Implementation in C)

Tags: html, character-encoding

I want to use URL encoder for my C program. I am wondering if there is any freely available URL encoding function implemented in C (on the web)??? I tried searching it, but couldn't  get one :(

Answer (score 0):

I find the [standard for URL's](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) isn't that hard. You can even limit yourself to HTTP URL's in most cases. It's pretty straight-forward to create your own urlencoder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any serious development in C, you should really look into using the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/modules.html) and [APR Utilities](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.3/group___a_p_r___util___u_r_i.html) libraries from [Apache](http://apr.apache.org/).